# Interpolating Strings Using jq

Tags: linux, bash, jq

I'm using jq to parse JSON data and pull out a value based on a dynamic key value given as a command line argument. I noticed that this works, but I'm skeptical about how it's interpolating `$v` within the single quotes. Is it possible to rewrite the expression `'.["\($v)"]'` within double quotes? What am I doing wrong?

Trying the following doesn't work for whatever reason:

`recipe_url=$(cat ./*.json | jq -r --arg v "$recipe_key" ".[\"\\($v)\"]")`

However, this does:

```
recipe_key='Wilted Greens' # example key to interpolate

recipe_url=$(cat ./*.json | jq -r --arg v "$recipe_key" '.["\($v)"]') # works!
```

Comment: Both of you are correct, and I was able to get two perspectives from the problem. The main thing to focus on is why I was wrong to continue down the path of using double quotes and derive an answer from that. That's what makes Stackoverflow great; it's more about arriving to the answer, rather than getting an definitive one.

Comment: I didn't say anything about "good" and "bad". I indicated a lack of understanding as to why the OP wanted to use double quotes when single quotes avoid any and all interpolation of exactly the sort he was trying to avoid and which interpolation was the *exact* problem he was posting about.

Comment: @EtanReisner my point is that it is not important **why** he wants to do it the "bad" way. Show him the "bad" way as I have done, along with a "better" way if you like, then let him decide.

Comment: You keep saying "bad". I didn't say that. I was *directly* responding to the implied reasoning in the post. He said he wants to avoid interpolation while simultaneously asking how to get his code working while having just *enabled* interpolation instead of using the single quotes he started with which *don't interpolate*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not escaped the `$v`, so Bash thinks it is a Bash variable, probably an empty one.
Try this

```
".[\"\\(\$v)\"]"
#       ^
#       |
#       --- notice
```

In my opinion, it is better in this situation to use use `--arg` with single quotes. `--arg` was implemented similar to awk `-v`, to fix exactly this type of situation with quoting headaches.

Comment: Son of a.. I spent hours trying to get this right. How did you figure that it was thinking of it as a bash variable? Also, do you feel that doing it this way makes more sense versus using single quotes?

Comment: +1 Once again, thanks Steven. I really needed a second opinion on this and what you're saying makes much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

> I noticed that this works, but I'm skeptical about how it's interpolating $v within the single quotes.

Single quotes **don't** interpolate variables or evaluate anything else.

**Nothing** is magical within single quotes. You can't even escape single quotes within single quotes.

The quoting/escaping problem you are having exists only because you are attempting to use double quotes instead of single quotes here.